# How to solve this JNA issue?

Tags: java, windows

I have application which use JNA and gets the audio and video. It works in my Linux box. But when i am testing it in Windows. It just never working. Because i am still learning, i will appreciate your suggestion how to fix it, i already spent few days and weeks only to work it out, but just dont get this why JAVA does not work simply, its a cross platform. Why should it require again System path or etc configuration.

I am totally lost now, why it works in Linux and it does not work in Windows XP ? How can i run it then ?

```
Inside the lib direcotry i have my JNA and Audio libraries.
C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\test>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 680F-0963

 Directory of C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\test

19/12/2010  22:09    <DIR>          .
19/12/2010  22:09    <DIR>          ..
19/12/2010  22:09            51.791 Audio.jar
19/12/2010  22:09    <DIR>          lib
               1 File(s)         51.791 bytes
               3 Dir(s)     487.002.112 bytes free



Now trying to run Audio.jar, gets Fail 1:

C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\test>java -Djava.library.path=~/jni -jar
Audio.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load librar
y gstreamer-0.10
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadWin32Library(GNative.java:83)
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadLibrary(GNative.java:43)
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative.load(GstNative.java:42)
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative.load(GstNative.java:39)
        at org.gstreamer.Gst.<clinit>(Gst.java:59)
        at video.MyVideo.simpletest(MyVideo.java:31)
        at sipphone.MainApplet.run(MainApplet.java:58)
        at sipphone.MainApplet.main(MainApplet.java:43)


Fail 2:
C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\test>java -Djna.library.path=. -jar Audio
.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load librar
y gstreamer-0.10
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadWin32Library(GNative.java:83)
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadLibrary(GNative.java:43)
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative.load(GstNative.java:42)
        at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GstNative.load(GstNative.java:39)
        at org.gstreamer.Gst.<clinit>(Gst.java:59)
        at video.MyVideo.simpletest(MyVideo.java:31)
        at sipphone.MainApplet.run(MainApplet.java:58)
        at sipphone.MainApplet.main(MainApplet.java:43)
```

Comment: I might be stating the obvious, but did you remember to build the library for Windows too? So, is there a `gstreamer-0.10.dll` in you `lib` directory?

Comment: This is what i have in lib Directory of C:\Documents and Settings\test\Desktop\test\lib

19/12/2010  22:09    <DIR>          .
19/12/2010  22:09    <DIR>          ..
19/12/2010  22:09           806.222 gstreamer-java-1.4.jar
19/12/2010  22:09           629.821 jna-3.0.4.jar
               2 File(s)      1.436.043 bytes
               2 Dir(s)     486.473.728 bytes free

Comment: I'm not familiar with gstreamer, but from first impression, you should in some way install GStream on you Windows box, and point the `jna.library.path` (probably not `java.library.path`) to the location where it keeps its DLLs. That, or ship the DLLs along.

Comment: That means, its a second installation!! for every Windows user i have to mention they need to download those DLL files separately ? That means also its impossible to do this using java applet (if i want minimize the installation procedure) ?

Comment: Your Linux machine will have something a file with a name like `libgstreamer-0.10.so` in some location, probably `/usr/lib`. GStreamer is an external dependency to your application, so your choices are (a) requiring installation of GStreamer on each user's system, or (b) shipping the libraries along with your application, which may or may not be an option for GStreamer.

Comment: I think this defination is very transparent. Which clearly mention that only in case for "GStreamer" implementation it is impossible to deploy via JAVA Applet. It must has to be installed as second method. Where many developers disagreed with me, and told its running with Java Applet. Do you technically agree with what i am trying to mention ? ex: www.phonefromhere.com  (works directly without second installation) but if i use Gstreamer it wont behave same like this url application.

Comment: In general, applets _can_ use native code, but I don't think that solves your problem. If you're interested in audio input in an applet, you could try the Java Sound API ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/sound/index.html ).

Comment: Thank you very much, i appreciate your suggestion. The reason i took Gstreamer is because it can handle Ultra sound above 48 Khz to 192 Khz. Which Java natural api cant do for me. So, i am now thinking should i stay with GStreamer or Should i look something else which can be a suitable for Java Applets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have the DLL installed, or at least in your JNA library path as others have pointed out.

It does add an extra dependency on Windows. It would be an extra dependency on Linux but gstreamer is preinstalled by your distribution. I ran into this same problem when I was making something to use a USB port from Java.

The only solution I know of to avoid the DLL would be to have a second version of the code you could call on Windows that would only use Win32 stuff (i.e. stuff that ships with Windows) but that would be a very large undertaking.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Still i see lot of troubles with this. I can do a web browser based application for Linux/Windows. But cant for Mac if i plan to move forward with GStream and make 92 khz to 192 Khz audio transmission. I am thinking my project will be failure, to get success moving forward with WEB Browser. If i have to make above 48 khz.

Answer (score 1):

trying to run mediarenderer from cling package, I had the same error on windows xp.
i got the right `libgstreamer-0.10.so` from package `GStreamer-WinBuilds-GPL-x86-Beta04-0.10.7.msi` found in https://code.google.com/archive/p/ossbuild/downloads

once installed (environment variables `PATH` (for dependencies) and `OSSBUILD_GSTREAMER_DIR` set), 
in a prompt, I was finally able to run mediarenderer using the following syntax to introduce lib's path :

```
Z:\Downloads\cling-distribution-2.1.0\cling-distribution-2.1.0\mediarenderer\target>java -Djna.library.path="C:\Program Files\OSSBuild\GStreamer\v0.10.7\bin" -jar cling-mediarenderer-2.1.0-standalone.jar
```

hope this helps as a starting point !

Answer (score -1):

For Fail 1: I don't believe that the `~/` syntax will work on Windows.  Try `%HOME%\` instead.  The [tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) happens in Bash, so things are a bit different in Windows.

For Fail 2: It doesn't look like the .dll is in your test directory, and you're setting the `jna.library.path` to `.`.

If the .dll's are in your lib directory, then shouldn't the paths be set to that directory, instead of `~/jni` and `.`?

Comment: if i have .jar why again i need .dll ? why Audio.jar then executes but not the .jar for JNA's ?

Comment: even if i do <applet code="sipphone.MainApplet" width=200 height=200 archive="Audio.jar" > it works but it does not load the JNA ? But its a jar from Linux, what is the point that i must have to put then DLL.

Comment: Tried this but no luck, fails. \test>java -Djna.library.path=lib -jar Aud
io.jar java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load librar
y gstreamer-0.10
at org.gstreamer.lowlevel.GNative.loadWin32Library(GNative.java:83)